# Умные указатели и наследование от QObject

Tags: c++, qt, указатели, qt5, smart-pointer

Один человек сказал мне, что для классов наследуемых от QObject не имеет смысла использовать умные указатели. (У меня окна в классах были как std::unique_ptr). Например:

```
std::unique_ptr<Commands> commands; // объявление в заголовочнике


commands = std::make_unique<Commands>(); // создание в cpp
```

Собственно, было сказано, что "для классов наследуемых от QObject не имеет смысла использовать умные указатели" и нужно заменить на обычные.
Хочется понять почему? Насколько это верно суждение?  Если можно, то какой-нибудь источник почитать на эту тему.

Comment: Видимо предполагается, что система родителей позаботится о правильной очистке памяти. Когда уничтожается объект, наследуемый от `QObject` он следом за собой уничтожает и всех своих детей, а те своих (о жестокий мир Qt). Насколько возможно во всех случаях упихать все объекты в дерево наследования, я с налету сказать не могу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Речь, скорее всего, о том, что в Qt принята концепция родительского объекта (см. [конструктор QObject](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#QObject)), который отвечает за владение дочерним объектом. Т.е. при разрушении родителя, уничтожается и его дочерние объекты. Если наложить эту концепцию на владение `std::unique_ptr`, то получим вероятность двойного удаления объекта.

Понятно, что в случаях, когда `QObject` создаётся динамически без родителя (`parent==nullptr`) и его надо как-то уничтожать, `std::unique_ptr` вполне имеет право на существование. Но так же можно использовать (но вроде бы уже не особо рекомендуется) и Qt-специфические обёртки типа `QScopedPointer`.

Т.е. `QObject` + `std::unique_ptr` вполне валидная пара, но при условии, что объектом не владеет (или не будет владеть) другой `QObject`. Иначе это как минимум будет выглядеть похожим на использование ремня и подтяжек одновременно, а максимум - приведёт к проблемам с освобождением памяти во время выполнения.

Comment: Сюда надо добавить два момента. Во-первых емнип при уничтожении объекта он удаляется из списка дочерних объектов своего родителя, поэтому даже при использовании родителей-детей и умных указателей, двойного удаления не будет. Во-вторых документация Qt не рекомендует использовать `delete` на объектах-наследниках `QObject`, это может привести к падению, опять же точно не помню условия, что-то с наличием событий в очереди для этого объекта. Для `QSharedPointer` и других можно передать кастомный deleter и использовать рекомендованную для QObject функцию `deleteLater()`

Comment: А можно для "особо одарённых" пояснить фразу `Т.е. при разрушении родителя, уничтожается и его дочерние объекты.` ? Вот у меня класс окошка, унаследованный от QWidget. И где-то в другом примерно таком же окне я создаю окно : `Window1 * mywindow`. Прошу прощения, конечно, за тупой вопрос) Но какой родитель должен тут разрушиться, чтобы этот указатель уничтожился и не произошло утечки памяти? Что-то я вообще не догоняю